# Internet dropping out for 1 sec about every 30 sec (with picture)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

[image]

When using something like skype, or playing an online game the internet drops out like you see in the picture is an example of it when i'm using skype.

This has been happening for about 2-3 weeks now, I asked my internet provider what to do so they sent us a new router. but now that we have the new one the problems still consist. I have tested and it happens on all the computer in the house.

If someone knows the fix or what is wrong with it would be great!

Comment: What kind of Internet connection is this? (Cable? DSL? Satellite?) Do you lose your connection to the router too? Does it happen to wired clients as well?

Comment: Restoration is almost instant, I really doubt its the WAN dropping out. OP Its likely bursts of wifi noise or mode switching. Are you able to login to your router?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Any luck?
I'm on ADSL2 line, the Wifi connection and router up time are not affected, but speed drops for 1-2 seconds every 30 seconds exactly. It's a very systematic downtime, tested through pings, downloading with wireshark speed monitoring..etc (on multiple devices). My ISP was not able to solve the problem. I hope anyone here can help